# Raspberry Pi: Detect camera with IF loop, gphoto2

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to detect if a camera is found for gphoto2, or not.

I've posted in the gphoto2 forum, but figured I'd try here too. One can issue the command, gphoto2 --auto-detect, and it will list cameras that are detected.

I'm running a large python script that at one point, calls gphoto2 to take a picture and download the image. I'm wanting to find a statement that I can put in an IF Loop, to where the take picture and download image command is only issued after entering in the loop if the camera is detected.

Answer (score 1):

quick google reveals python bindings for gphoto2 http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Remote_control_with_PTP_and_Python .

Other variant is to call a console command i.e

```
from subprocess import call
call(["gphoto2", "--auto-detect"])
```

It is up to you how long you will wait for camera to be detectend before you give up.

If you are going with loop, remember to put some sleep command in.

```
timeout = time.time() + 60
detected = False
while time.time() < timeout:
    if is_device_available():
        detected = True
        break
    # maybe show some feedback why he has to wait
    time.sleep(1)
if not detected:
    raise Exception('Camera device not detected')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, on the piggyphoto github page it says they lack full gphoto2 implementation, which I'd need to change some of the settings remotely on my camera. I understand the 
    if is_device_available():
        detected = True
but am unsure of what my "is_device_available()" would be in this instance

Comment: that would be function you define yourself where check and possibly store/cache available device you are going to use.